# How to mock a named import object type const in react native using jest?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

Hii everyone currently I'm using the following library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics

for my project but I stuck here when I'm trying to write the unit tests for it I have mocked the library like below

```
import ReactNativeBiometrics, { BiometryTypes } from 'react-native-biometrics';

jest.mock ('react-native-biometrics', () =>
{
  class ReactNativeBiometrics {

    constructor(){
    }
    isSensorAvailable() {
    
    }
    
  }
  return ReactNativeBiometrics;
});
```

Now I'm trying to mock

```
BiometryTypes
```

but its not getting mocked anyone can give some idea how this can be mocked.

BiometryTypes is exported like below

```
export declare const BiometryTypes: {
    TouchID: string;
    FaceID: string;
    Biometrics: string;
};
```

I tried like below but its not working

```
import { BiometryTypes } from 'react-native-biometrics';
import * as all from 'react-native-biometrics';

const  TouchID = 'TouchID' ;
all.BiometryTypes = {
  TouchID: TouchID,
  FaceID: TouchID
};
```

Comment: but why do you want to mock types?

Comment: hey, actually I have to show different messages as per the biometry type available on the device I mean if biometry is touchId I have to show enable touchId, or if its faceId I have to show enable faceId now when I'm trying to write unit test for it I'm not able to mock the biometry type so that I can check the message in unit test.

Comment: my bad, it were not types, but typed constant

Comment: how can I mock those typed constants I tried several ways but that doesn't work. Any reference or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine named and default mocks in factory function:

```
jest.mock ('react-native-biometrics', () =>
{
  class ReactNativeBiometrics {
     ......
  }
  return { 
    __esModule: true
    default: ReactNativeBiometrics,
    BiometryTypes: { TouchID: 'mock1', FaceID: 'mock2', .... } // static values
  };
});
```

[Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) clarify why this is necessary:

> When using the factory parameter for an ES6 module with a default export, the `__esModule: true` property needs to be specified. This property is normally generated by Babel / TypeScript, but here it needs to be set manually. When importing a default export, it's an instruction to import the property named `default` from the export object

Beware! With this approach, object `BiometryTypes` will be mocked once and forever, while you probably want to test different variants of it. Maybe `doMock` and `unmock` could help to overcome this, but in my opinion much much more reliable is to create several `.test.js` files, each one would mock `BiometryTypes` in unique way(e.g. `FaceID_and_TouchID.test.js`, `TouchID-only.test.js` etc). `jest.mock` is quite magical because it's hoisted to the very top, using `unmock`/`doMock` may break if values have already caught by other modules or closures in the same module.